# ASP.NET MVC reuse code between different website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two asp.net mvc website, they have the same page to update account data.

How to separate the repeated code(controller, *.cshtml, *.js, *.css... etc) for better maintainability? I don't want to modify code from one website and copy it to the other.

I have tried creating new website project only contains account pages, but the static files(*.js, *.css) can't be reused in this way.

Comment: If you have two websites, shouldn't the project be already separated? I don't know if it is just me because I can't seem to understand your question. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Ephraim I don't want to modify code from one website and copy it to the other.

Comment: You can create project templates, although that only works for when you start a project. You might find it easiest to package the shared code into NuGet packages, which would also allow you to reuse your CSS files, etc.

Comment: Why not make a shared class library between the two websites? This is assuming that want to have the exact same files to share between the two websites and you don't want to copy and paste each way.